# How to disable built-in rules?

Tags: parsing, built-in, bnfc

How can I disable all BNFC built-in rules, like `Ident`, `Integer` or the spaces being used to separate tokens?

I found them *useless* and *annoying* since they interfere with the parsers I'm trying to write.

I already tried to re-define them but it seems like the lexer continues to generate the rules for them. I could manually delete them from the generated files but I'm completely against modifying machine generated code.

---

Long version on *why* they are annoying.

I'm just starting to learn how to use BNFC. The first thing I tried is to convert a previous work of mine from Alex to BNFC. In particular I want to match only "good" roman numerals. I thought it would be quite simple:
A roman numeral can be seen as a sequence like

```
<thousand-part> <hundred-part> <tens-part> <unit-part>
```

Where they cannot all be empty. So a numeral either has a non-empty `thousand-part` and can be whatever in the rest, or it has an empty `thousand-part` and thus either `hundred-` or `tens-` or `unit-` `part` must be non empty. The same thing can be iterated until the base case of units.

So I came up with this, which is more or less a direct translation of what I did in Alex:

```
N1.            Numeral ::= TokThousands HundredNumber     ;
N2.            Numeral ::= HundredNumberNE                ; --NE = Not Empty
N3.      HundredNumber ::=                                ;
N4.      HundredNumber ::= HundredNumberNE                ;
N5.    HundredNumberNE ::= TokHundreds TensNumber         ;
N6.    HundredNumberNE ::= TensNumberNE                   ;
N7.         TensNumber ::=                                ;
N8.         TensNumber ::= TensNumberNE                   ;
N9.       TensNumberNE ::= TokTens UnitNumber             ;
N10.      TensNumberNE ::= UnitNumberNE                   ;
N11.        UnitNumber ::=                                ;
N12.        UnitNumber ::= UnitNumberNE                   ;
N13.      UnitNumberNE ::= TokUnits                       ;


token TokThousands ({"MMM"} | {"MM"} | {"M"}) ;  -- No x{m,n} in BNFC regexes?
token TokHundreds  ({"CM"} | {"DCCC"} | {"DCC"} | {"DC"} | {"D"} | {"CD"} | {"CCC"} | {"CC"} | {"C"}) ;
token TokTens      ({"IC"} | {"XC"} | {"LXXX"} | {"LXX"} | {"LX"} | {"LX"} | {"L"} | {"IL"} | {"XL"} | {"XXX"} | {"XX"} | {"X"}) ;
token TokUnits     ({"IX"} | {"VIII"} | {"VII"} | {"VI"} | {"V"} | {"IV"} | {"III"} | {"II"} | {"I"}) ;
```

Now, the problem is that if I try to build this parser, when giving an input like:

```
MMI
```

Or in general a numeral that has more than one of the `*-part`s not empty, the parser gives an error because BNFC cannot match `MMI` with a single token and thus *it uses the built-in `Ident` rule*. Since the rule doesn't appear in the grammar it raises a parsing error, although the input string is perfectly fine by the grammar I defined, it's the *bogus* `Ident` rule that's in the way.

Note: I verified that if I separate the different parts with spaces I get the correct input, but later on I want to put spaces to separate whole numbers, not their tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to BNFC's [documentation](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2011/course/TIN321/lectures/bnfc-tutorial.html#toc45):

> These types are hard-coded and cannot be value types of rules

Which means that: **there is no way to disable built-in rules without modifying the generated code**. The only option would be to write a script that automatically deletes the bogus rules from the generated file and always use a `Makefile` to build the lexers and parser, to avoid forgetting that step.

It seems like the authors *deliberately* decided to reduce the flexibility of BNFC *imposing* their definition of what an integer literal is, what an identifier should look like, how tokens should be separated etc.
They *could* have provided defaults rules, allowing to disable them with some option, but they decided that if you don't agree with their definitions then you shouldn't use their tool at all.